# java.lang.VerifyError when downloading data with jsoup in Android N

Tags: java, android, jsoup, verifyerror

I compiled my Android app for the new Android N version and then tried to test it on an emulator. It runs normally until I try to download and parse some website data using the "jsoup" library. Then I get this java.lang.VerifyError:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                 Process: com.masrepus.vplanapp, PID: 6584
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState$7: boolean org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState$7.process(org.jsoup.parser.Token, org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder) failed to verify: boolean org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState$7.process(org.jsoup.parser.Token, org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder): [0x140B] Invalid reg type for array index (Reference: org.jsoup.nodes.Node[]) (declaration of 'org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState$7' appears in /data/app/com.masrepus.vplanapp-2/base.apk)
                                                                     at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState.<clinit>(HtmlTreeBuilderState.java:246)
                                                                     at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.parse(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:53)
                                                                     at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parseInput(Parser.java:30)
                                                                     at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:81)
                                                                     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:517)
                                                                     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.post(HttpConnection.java:174)
                                                                     at com.masrepus.vplanapp.network.AsyncDownloader.updateAvailableFilesList(AsyncDownloader.java:961)
                                                                     at com.masrepus.vplanapp.network.AsyncDownloader.downloadVplan(AsyncDownloader.java:237)
                                                                     at com.masrepus.vplanapp.network.AsyncDownloader.doInBackground(AsyncDownloader.java:135)
                                                                     at com.masrepus.vplanapp.network.AsyncDownloader.doInBackground(AsyncDownloader.java:113)
                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

While researching on VerifyErrors, I came across some solutions, like cleaning the project build folder. But those solutions didn't help.
What I am wondering is, what `[0x140B] Invalid reg type for array index` means. This may be the thing I have to resolve, but I don't know how.

Edit:
So I dove a bit deeper into the problem and located the crash inside the block named "InBody" in [org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/jsoup-1.9.2/src/main/java/org/jsoup/parser/HtmlTreeBuilderState.java), lines 244-759. I don't know why, but when I set breakpoints there, the program never stops there, so I have no clue at which exact position inside this block the crash happens. But as the error message speaks of some sort of array index, I figured it might be one of the **6** for-loops I found that have something to do with the data type "Element": They are at lines 305, 388, 561, 582, 602 and 640

Comment: Please post your code for `doInBackgraound()`.

Comment: If you want to have a look at the code, here is the file: https://github.com/Masrepus/VPlan/blob/improvements/app/src/main/java/com/masrepus/vplanapp/network/AsyncDownloader.java but in short what happens before the crash is this: `Jsoup.connect("somestring").header("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding).post();`

Comment: @JoelMin I just edited my question with more infos I gathered while debugging, maybe you can give me some clues...

Comment: Hey @Masrepus, this doesn't seem to be your fault but the Jsoup library's. There could be a few reasons for this including too many local variables. What I would suggest is that try to build and run your app with lower version of Android, maybe Marshmallow? If it does not happen on Marshmallow, then I would say that the issue is caused by some update on Dalvik for Android N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable jack.

I got the same error when I enable jack. I disabled jack and compiled, no error. Then I copied jsoup source code to my project folder, enabled jack and compiled, no error. So I think it is a bug of jill, the tool to convert *.class to *.jack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Turning off jack really did help. Now after some sdk updates the bug there seems fixed as turning on jack is working again.